# How to clear and undo the value of a specific cell in Google Sheet by app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

How to clear and undo the value of a specific cell in Google Sheets by App Script?

**This should be Automate done by using a trigger once a week.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    function clearData() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var data = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); // the name of your sheet
      data.getRange("B2").clearContent(); // the cell you want to clear
}
```

You'll just need to set up a trigger to run whenever you want it to.

Comment: thank you , but this is just for clearing content , how to undo the cleared content?

Comment: Why would you want to undo it? What is the exact purpose?

Comment: When I call the sitemap of a site, the information is not updated until I clear the address field once and undo it again. Currently I do this manually. And I need to automate this work.